# How to keep code-folding on save in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on some fairly large files in Visual Studio code and to save time I fold away functions and scopes, that I do not want to see. Everytime I save, which I do fairly often just out of habit, all the folds expand again and the current position on screen changes.

Since the only settings I could find were:

```
"editor.folding": true,
"editor.showFoldingControls": "mouseover",
```

the question is: How can I keep my folds upon saving?

Comment: I wonder if you have another setting or extension that conflicts with vscode's folding because my folds are saved and reused, even when restarting vscode.

Comment: That's odd. At home it works. I need to double check this in the office tomorrow. Maybe its related to the fact, that at work I'm working on files located on a network share.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for bringing up the extensions Mark. It was indeed an extension: `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter`.

Once this was disabled, the folding kept its state after saving.

Comment: Nope. It is not `lonefy`

Comment: In my case it was. Wouldn't have marked my answer as solved otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, this help me

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that comes across this like me, I didn't have `prettier`, `sort-imports`, or `lonefy`.  I was able to resolve by updating the 'folding strategy' setting from 'auto' to 'indentation' and it kept my folds persistent through saving and particularly in my case deploying code using the Salesforce CLI extension.

> https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#folding

Comment: I think its some internal issue because it works sometimes and sometimes not without any changes to settings

Answer (score 7):

For me it was the [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) plugin :(

Here is the closed issue: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/408.

At the moment, there doesn't seem to be a fix.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and it turned out to be the **sort-imports** extension. Removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: Well, but it is very useful information for follow-up readers!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I found this in the settings and it fixes the problem for prettier.

`"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable"`

Answer (score 0):

Following the formatting extensions hint, I tried disabling the eslint extension and my folded sections persisted on save-quit-launch as expected.  What's weird is that it's still fixed, even after re-enabling eslint.